# How to give different content to every cell in the table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put 4 arrows, top, left, right and bottom in a table using content `nth-chid()` method, I have a table of 3 rows and 3 columns, the `nth-child()` works on the first row, but when I want to change `nth-child(4)` doesn't work because it was changed for the entire column.
The table:

```
<div class="help-block">
    <table class="css-context-explorer-orientation-widget">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
</div>
```

Please find the CSS [here and Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gz7fc4hL/3/) example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `nth-child` incorrectly in this case. You would probably want to also target the `nth-child` of the `tr` elements as well, then target the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd `td` below that.

The selector would be like this:

```
.help-block .css-context-explorer-orientation-widget tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3):before
```

which targets the 2nd row, 3rd column.

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gz7fc4hL/6/

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this -

```css
.help-block  td {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.help-block  td:before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "\e04f";
    position: absolute;
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(1)  td:nth-child(1):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "1";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(1)  td:nth-child(2):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "2";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(1)  td:nth-child(3):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "3";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(1):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "4";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(2):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "5";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(3):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "6";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(3)  td:nth-child(1):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "7";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(3)  td:nth-child(2):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "8";
}
.help-block tr:nth-child(3)  td:nth-child(3):before {
    font-family: icons;
    content: "9";
}
```

```html
<div class="help-block">
 <table class="css-context-explorer-orientation-widget">
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```